# RegOpenKeyEx fails on Windows XP only

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I have a piece of code which looks for registry entries. In its current form below it works fine on Vista and 7, however it returns either error code 2 or 87 on XP.

Current code (working on greater than XP):

```
dwRet = RegOpenKeyEx( hKeyUsed, strRegCheck, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey ) ;

if ( dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
{
    dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, strRegValue, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) PerfData, &cbData );

    while ( dwRet == ERROR_MORE_DATA )
    {
        // Get a buffer that is big enough.
        BufferSize += BYTEINCREMENT;
        PerfData = (PPERF_DATA_BLOCK) realloc( PerfData, BufferSize );
        cbData = BufferSize;
        dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) PerfData, &cbData );
    }
    if ( dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        strSourcePath = PerfData->Signature;
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is the first line which seems to be the issue, and the second parameter which is causing it. Here is the MSDN documentation on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx

strRegCheck is of type CString. If, on Windows XP, I change this for

```
const LPCWSTR sKey = _T("CLSID\\{2933BF90-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}\\VersionList");
```

and obviously change the second parameter for 'sKey' then we work again.

If I set sKey to be:

```
const LPCTSTR sKey = strRegCheck.GetBuffer(strRegCheck.GetLength());
```

then I am back into the land of failing. Interestingly, if I have RegEdit open at the same time, and have the key I am searching for open, then it does't fail. Also, I am either failing with error 2 or 87.

I have read loads of other threads on this but no definitive answer. I am in a bit of rush to get this finished so any pointers anyone could give me would be greatly received.

Comment: When you test on Windows 7 and Windows XP, are you testing the same binary? Or, are you compiling on Windows 7 and testing and compiling on Windows XP and testing?

Comment: system error code `2` is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. May be this registry key does not exist on your XP system?

Comment: hmjd - I am testing with the same binary. I have tried compiling on both in turn with the same results.

Comment: Lol4t0 - Yep, I know thats what the error code is. But it definitely does exist. And still, opening the key in regedit makes the whole thing work, so if the reg entry didn't exist then that would be impossible.

Comment: It is a Unicode project and im starting to wonder whether I've fallen into some casting mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the variables had escaped backslashes. These strings are read in from a text file. I replaced the double backslashes for single ones and it works. Even so, could anyone explain to me why this is because I'd like to understand better. I'd quite like to understand how Vista and 7 work and yet XP doesn't.